# How to Implement FlashToggle button in the camera app using cameraX?

Tags: android, android-camerax, flashlight

How to Implement FlashToggle  button in the camera app using cameraX?
The flashlight should work properly along with the camera?

```
 @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private fun toggleFlash()
{
    if(flash_toggle.isChecked)
    {
        try {
            cameraManager.setTorchMode(getCameraID, true)
        }
        catch(e: CameraAccessException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    else{
        try {
    cameraManager.setTorchMode(getCameraID,false)
        }
        catch(e: CameraAccessException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

I Have used this but it only works when camera is off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a flash when capturing an image you can use:

`imageCapture.flashMode = ImageCapture.FLASH_MODE_ON` for flash on

`imageCapture.flashMode = ImageCapture.FLASH_MODE_OFF` for flash off

`imageCapture.flashMode = ImageCapture.FLASH_MODE_AUTO` for flash auto

If you want to use the torch(flashlight), you can use:

```kotlin
// Enable torch
camera.cameraControl.enableTorch(true)

// Disable torch
camera.cameraControl.enableTorch(false)
```

Enable torch only after binding use cases.

To obtain the `Camera` instance use:

```kotlin
camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(...)
```